# Автоматическая генерация логов или принт-аутов к методам (функциям) со всеми параметрами для дебага

Tags: java, логирование

Ищу способ автоматической генерации логов. Для *Log4j* автоматически вставлять в исходный код `logger("...")`, принтаутов `System. out. println("...")` сообщений, сгенерированных  по заголовку метода, значению параметров функций или по различным шаблонам.
Для дебага, чтобы просмотреть правильность параметров метода и изменение значений переменных.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд подключить аспекты - либо через Spring, либо сам AspectJ, в принципе можно и Guice. И в аспектах уже написать. что хочется.